# How to configure Laravel Passport's '/oauth/token' rate limit?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, rate-limiting

I would like to be able to configure the throttle that is placed on Laravel Passport's `oauth/token` endpoint.

I've tracked it down to the `RouteRegistrar.php` file where the endpoint is registered:

```php
        $this->router->post('/token', [
            'uses' => 'AccessTokenController@issueToken',
            'as' => 'passport.token',
            'middleware' => 'throttle',
        ]);
```

Can the rate of this throttle be set somewhere without having to fork the Passport package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following code while registering `Routes` for `Passport` in `boot` function of `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` will set throttle limit to 100 requests per minute. `throttle:100,1` could be changed to increase or decrease throttle to desired limit. This actually registers the route before default `RouteRegistrar` tries to register all passport routes in `RouteRegistrar.php`

```
    Passport::routes(
        function($routeRegistrar){
            $routeRegistrar->all();
            Route::post('/token', [
                'uses' => 'AccessTokenController@issueToken',
                'middleware' => 'throttle:100,1',
            ]);
        }
    );
```

Comment: I suppose I should also add the `as => 'passport.token'` field if I want to minimize possible changes in behavior?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be better if you have that in the package. In my version, I do not have it that's why I did not use that.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is no longer valid, as the latest version of Passport (v11 as of this comment) removes the `routes()` static method. I asked about this on the [PR that removed it](https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/1464#issuecomment-1302460087), but the response was kinda generic and didn't seem to help with this throttling issue. Can this answer please be updated to account for Passport v11?

Comment: @Sturm Were you able to make this work with the updated Passport?

I think using `Passport::ignoreRoutes()`  with this may work

Route::group([
                'as' => 'passport.',
                'prefix' => config('passport.path', 'oauth'),
                'namespace' => 'Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers',], function () {
                $this->loadRoutesFrom({PATH_TO_PASSPORT.'/routes/web.php');
Route::post('/token', [
                'uses' => 'AccessTokenController@issueToken',
                'middleware' => 'throttle:100,1',
            ]);
});

Comment: @UmairMalhi Sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure we want to use `Route::group()` because our project has an extremely complex route file. In addition, we use Dingo for the API and Passport because it's a legacy app. What I wound up doing (and which seems to work) is: `$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v2', function ($api) {
    $api->post('/token', [
        'uses' => 'AccessTokenController@issueToken',
        'as' => 'token',
        'middleware' => 'throttle:' . config('throttle_limit_authservice') . ',1',
    ]);
    // All the routes here.
});`